# One of your SonarQube server cannot be reached. Please check your connection settings

Tags: eclipse, configuration, sonarqube

I am new to Sonar and I am trying to install and configure Sonar in my local system. I have followed the steps mentioned [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW36x.png) for installing sonar and integrating it with eclipse, but  I can not associate my project with sonar and getting exception  One of your SonarQube server cannot be reached. Please check your connection settings. please see the below screen shots, and let me know if i am missing something.

[image: Project association]
[image: Sonar Server error message]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue just now.

What helped me in the end was to test the server connection from Eclipse's `Window -> Settings -> SonarQube -> Servers -> http://localhost:9000 -> Edit -> Test connection`

I am running a fresh SonarQube installation and did not specify a username nor a password. The test returned *Successfully Connected!* and thereafter SonarQube markers showed up in the source code as well as in the SonarQube issues tab.

Answer (score 1):

From the http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/ did you install sonarqube and started the service? If you didn't you need to do it first. When you start service you will see the connection string. 
And then in SoberQube configuration in Eclipse instead of 
    `http://localhost:9000` try     `http://0.0.0.0:9000`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your java runtime(JRE) , what you need to do is to download a new JRE from oracle : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html
and install it , then try again and it should work

a note : 
only install jre and not jdk , when finished check in terminal using java -version command if the version is according to what you have just installed .
good luck !