# Unknown version for SonarQube server (http://localhost:9000). Please check server is reachable

Tags: eclipse, maven, sonarqube

I Have installed Sonar in my system, and eclipse plugin of the same.

I am following below  mentioned steps

1. Running StartSonar.bat
2. Going to my  project  directory where POM.XML  is located of my project  and run the command

   ```
   mvn sonar:sonar
   ```
3. Eclipse SonarQuber : Analysis project .

I keep  on getting error:

> Unknown version for SonarQube server . Please check server is reachable.

And also , sonar analysis is not working from eclipse, I mean if I correct the error  indicated by sonar and do sonar analysis again, it shows error  at the same.

However if  I do it from command prompt it is working fine. Please help  me  on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Though it is not a direct ans but still here is what I tried and worked for me.

1. Check if SONAR server is reachable. Read the question at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211215](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211215/one-of-your-sonarqube-server-cannot-be-reached-please-check-your-connection-set) to configure/correct the server connectivity issue. Point to note is providing `username` and `password` and testing the connection.
2. Navigate to your project root `pom.xml` in command prompt.
3. fire`mvn sonar:sonar`
4. Results gets published in `http://localhost:9000`

Answer (score 1):

The miraculously simple answer for me was:

1. Go to the sonar server preferences under Window->Preferences->SonarQube->Server
2. Choose the server and click edit
3. assuming you have entered the correct username and password (or nothing if the settings on your sonar server are allow anonymous analyzing)
4. Press test connection

On the top of the window it should state "Successfully connected!" and when you try to analyze the project again the error is gone.

May be a bug in the eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

After starting the sonar server which is installed in ur drive,,,
try to fetch with http://localhost:9000 and
 give the test properties "admin" and "admin" as username and password.

It will work